# How to include external javascript script in cucumber-capybara test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

So I'm writing an integration test using Capybara Webkit and Cucumber for a feature that uses the popular jQueryUI Sortable plugin. Unfortunately Capybara doesn't support this and I found this jQuery library that's used to test it https://github.com/mattheworiordan/jquery.simulate.drag-sortable.js. The author says to use the $.getScript function and get it from somewhere else to include it into a test but that seems like awful practice, making a network request when you don't really need it. The solution I came up with is sticking it into the application.html.erb file as a conditional on `Rails.env == 'test'` but that's almost as bad. Ideally I'd like to know if there is a way to include javascripts in cucumber/capybara configurations

Comment: You can just add the script in `app/assets/javascripts` and serve it locally instead.

Comment: "The solution I came up with is sticking it into the application.html.erb file as a conditional on Rails.env == 'test' but that's almost as bad. Ideally I'd like to know if there is a way to include javascripts in cucumber/capybara configurations"

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, you would use `evaluate_script` to pull the script in with `$.getScript`. You could load the javascript file contents with ruby and then feed it to `evaluate_script` but I doubt it will have any performance benefits. Webkit might actually load the script faster than Ruby or if it is served locally or if it is cached in the test browser.

Comment: "The author says to use the $.getScript function and get it from somewhere else to include it into a test but that seems like awful practice, making a network request when you don't really need it."

Comment: All the info about Capybara drag_to not working with jqueryUI Sortable seem to be from a number of years ago -- have you actually tried a modern version of capybara-webkit with this?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, it doesn't seem to be working either, also I refined my problem and tried simulating it myself but that doesn't seem to be working either, seems like it could be a [dom issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618611/access-dom-from-capybara-webkit-execute-script)