# Access DOM from capybara-webkit #execute_script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, capybara, capybara-webkit

So I'm trying to test that the jQueryUI sortable library triggers an ajax request and I haven't been successful at triggering it, I've tried this with the jquery.simulate.drag-sortable.js library, but to no avail. I've also tried it with the execute script function, also to no avail. I am trying to manually trigger the sortable deactivate event because `jQuery.trigger()` doesn't seem to work with it even in the browser. The script that is executed is `$sortable.sortable("option", "deactivate")(event, ui)` with event and ui properly injected, this code works when I enter it directly into the browser.

The problem seems to stem from not being able to access the DOM. When I enable the debug mode on the driver the error is `TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$sortable.sortable("option", "deactivate")(event, ui)')`. Digging a little deeper reveals that the Javascript driver can't access DOM nodes within `#execute_javascript`. When I enter `console.log(document.getElementById('sortable'));` The response is `'null'`.

Any thoughts on how to trigger the jQueryUI sortable function with the deactivate event using capybara-webkit?

Comment: `#execute_script` never returns a response as documented in Capybara.  You want `#evaluate_script` if you want to get a response from the javascript you're running in the page

Comment: Looking at the jquery-ui docs for sortable http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/ - I don't see any "deactivate" option, so I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: Did you not read it? http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-deactivate

Comment: Yes I read it - that's an event the control fires, your code above is calling the method that changes an option though - and under the "options" list there is no deactivate

Comment: You should've said something. Either way I updated it to try and fire off the event and it didn't work either

Comment: Wow, just wow -- I did say something and you accused me of not reading -- done helping here

Comment: I meant you should've said something like "deactivate is not an option it's an event."